# Delphi 11 FormCreate not called

Tags: forms, delphi, oncreate

I have a `TRemote` class derived from `TForm`.

I want to setup some buttons callback, and place a specific Button+Path on the screen during the Form's `OnCreate` event.

But nothing happens!

When I place a breakpoint, it is never reached.

Can someone explain to me why?

```
procedure TRemote.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  ButtonPath1: TButtonPath;
begin
  ButtonPath1 := TButtonPath.Create(Self);
  ButtonPath1.Parent := Self;
  ButtonPath1.SetBounds(50, 50, ButtonPath1.Width, ButtonPath1.Height); // set the position of ButtonPath


  // Loop through components
  for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    // Check if it is a button ?
    if Components[I] is TButton then
    begin
      // Attach HandleButtonClick to OnClick event of this button
      TButton(Components[I]).OnClick := HandleButtonClick;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is not enough to add a method named `FormCreate` to the form class. You also need to assign this method to the form's `OnCreate` handler, probably using the Object Inspector. Alternatively, you can override the form's constructor.

Comment: Hello Andreas , I checked it, and FormCreate is assigned to the form's OnCreate handler on the Object Inspector

Comment: You could have assured that by also posting the relevant DFM file portion.

Comment: Perhaps more of a narrowing-down-the-problem exercise than anything, but try putting the code in an overridden form's `Create` method (as Andreas suggested) or overridden form's `Loaded` method, and see if it works in those places.

Comment: @Harvey If you double click on your form does the editor jumps to your `TRemote.FormCreate` method?  If not then the most liekly cause is the fact that Delphi IDE doesn't have all needed information about your derived from since it is not registered at design time. PS: Why are you looping through all forms components just to assign OnClick event method to the button you have just created. Why not just use `ButtonPath1.OnClick  := HandleButtonClick;` instead since you already have reference to your button readily available.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes when I double click it reaches the method. For the loop I have 20 buttons so with few lines I'm sure all have the same event method (when it will work)

Comment: @Philip I tried with `constructor TRemote.FormCreate(AOwner: TForm );
//  ....
//procedure TRemote.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  ButtonPath1: TButtonPath;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  ButtonPath1 := TButtonPath.Create(Self);` but without success

Comment: `FormCreate()` does not override the native constructor. You would need to `override` the virtual `Create()` constructor, eg : `constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; ... constructor TRemote.Create(AOwner: TComponent); var ... begin inherited Create(AOwner); ... end;`